# Framer Motion single axis layout animations on fixed element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I've been having trouble with constricting layout animations to a single axis on a fixed element.

[image: example of issue]

The underline should only move on x axis when switching tab. As you can see in the gif, the underline element thats following the active tab, is also moving on the y axis equal to the amount scrolled on the current page.
I've been able to achieve this on static elements using the `layoutRoot` property. https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1112

What I've tried:

1. Applied `layoutRoot` to the `li` and grandparent elements
2. Without the layout `property` on parent element
3. Removed absolute position from underline element

But have had no luck using the same method with fixed elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Underline element:

```
const Underline = ({ className = "", id = "underline", ...props }) => {
    return (
        <m.div
            {...props}
            layout="position"
            layoutId={id}
            className={`h-0.5 bg-green-light absolute bottom-2 inset-x-4 transition-colors ${className}`}
        />
    );
};
```

Parent element:

```
<m.footer
            variants={variants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            exit="hidden"
            className="fixed bottom-0 inset-x-0 bg-white h-[calc(theme(height.navbar)+theme(space.safe-bottom))] lg:hidden shadow-top flex justify-center border-t border-gray-normal z-50 px-default"
        >
            <nav className="w-full items-stretch">
                <m.ul layoutRoot className="flex text-xl h-navbar">
                    {sidebarLinks?.map((l, i) => {
                        // ....
                        const isActive =
                            router.pathname.split("/")[1] === path?.replace("/", "");
                        const disabled = l?.disabled;
                        return (
                            <m.li
                                key={i}
                                className="h-full w-full relative transition-colors"
                            >
                                
                                    <>
                                        <Link
                                            href={disabled ? router.asPath : path}
                                            className="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
                                        >
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={l?.icon} />
                                            <p className="text-xxs leading-none mt-1 font-semibold">
                                                {t(l?.title)}
                                            </p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </>
                                
                                {isActive && (
                                    <Underline id="footer" className="top-0 !inset-x-0" />
                                )}
                            </m.li>
                        );
                    })}
                </m.ul>
            </nav>
        </m.footer>
```

Sorry for the horrible formatting. Have no idea how to format from the stackoverflow text editor.

Comment: It's hard to help you without a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `style={{ originY: '0px' }}` to the **Underline** component

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did not work, but thanks for the suggestion!